# Detect change of top.location.href via jQuery

Tags: jquery, window, onchange

is there any way to detect a change of top.location.href or window.location.href in jQuery? Tried something like

```
top.location.href.change(function() {});
```

already, but it didn't work.

any ideas?

**Update:** I want to prevent frames from breaking out the box. The frame may not change the main page's top.location.href.

Thanks!
indect

Comment: What are you trying to catch exactly ? Changes via the history API ? You know that most changes of the top location will make your page refresh ?

Comment: What kind of change? A new URL, or an anchor?

Comment: Man I think you are detecting hashchange.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-Binding-Events-To-Non-DOM-Objects-With-jQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) { 
    var anchor = document.location.hash;
            if( anchor === '#first_one' ) {
                alert('url = #first');
            }else if ( anchor === '#second_one' ) {
                alert('url = #second');
            }else if ( anchor === '#third_one' ) {
                alert('url = #third');
            }
            console.log(anchor);
    });
});
```

[not working in all browser](http://caniuse.com/hashchange).

[**jquery-hashchange-plugin**](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: I'm trying to detect if a frame wants to break out and redirect the main page to another URL.

Comment: @indect so please update question with all requirement so OtherPeople can also help...thanx